# Interpretation of non-spontaneous Gibbs free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, work, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Good day guys,

I was reading some books on physical thermodynamics, they explain that for system undergoing a chemical reaction whose $\Delta G < 0$ indicating that the reaction can then provide us with a max non-PV work of $W_{max} = - \Delta G$

However, what happens when the reaction is not spontaneous, is $\Delta G$ the minimum work we need to supply? The books I have do not explicitly mention this statement, they only state it for work obtained from spontaneous reactions.

Comment: It's the amount of work you/surroundings must do to the system so that the (non-spontaneous) process goes forward. That is, $W=\Delta G$

Comment: Is it the total amount of work we must supply or the minimum ? One of my book presents this equation as an inequality: $W \le \delta G $.

Comment: the difference $\Delta G -W$ is the dissipated heat.

Comment: here are two similar questions for the Helmholtz free energy $F$ with obvious changes to your question on $G$ https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761649/difference-between-spontaneous-and-irreversible-process#mjx-eqn-1 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755441/free-energy-change-in-reversible-irreversible-processes

Comment: @RMS it’s the minimum.